# sign bit of a NAN in IEEE 754 standard

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

I want to perform a floating point single precision addition operation in which

A = + infinity ( 7F800000)
B = - infinity ( FF800000)

Will the result(A+B) be +NAN or -NAN ?

another related question :

We get qNAN if NAN propagates through the arithmetic operation.
Whereas sNAN represents an invalid exception operation.
So, the above operation will result into a sNAN. 
Is my understanding correct ?

Answer (score 6):

The IEEE 754 standard does not specify which representation of NaN you get when you apply an operation that produces a NaN. The only recommendation, not always followed, is that if the result is NaN because at least one of the operands is, then the result should have an identical representation to one of the NaN operands.

Producing a NaN from non-NaN operands may be an opportunity to interrupt the control flow (for instance, with a *trap*), depending how your system is set up. If the host system is not set up to interrupt the control flow immediately, the produced NaN is a quiet NaN.

Signaling NaNs are useful to fill up memory that should be considered uninitialized: this would cause an immediate exception instead of propagating a NaN value. It would not make sense for an arithmetic operation to return a signaling NaN, because the cause of the exception is the current operation (which signals the NaN, which in turn is either ignored or acted upon depending how the system is set up). Returning a signaling NaN would make it look as if the next operation is the cause of the exception.

NaN has its own [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) with a lot of information.

Comment: By "exception" in your second paragraph,  do you mean "trap"?

Comment: @tmyklebu I tried to use “exception” for all the ways the control flow can be interrupted, in the spirit of the phrase “optional exception handling in various forms, including traps and other models such as try/catch” in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754_revision . Is that wrong?

Comment: IEEE 754 uses "exception" in a different way than modern programming languages.  Division by zero, invalid operation, overflow, underflow, and inexact operation *are* exceptions, and the default way to handle each (infinity, NaN, infinity, zero, round, all the while setting a bit in some register) represent one of a few options.  Another option is to trap (on Linux, send a SIGFPE), which you can configure for each exception individually.  So I think you meant either "trap" instead of "raise an exception" or "is" instead of "may be." :)

Comment: @tmyklebu I have replaced the word “exception”, that I intended only for “IEEE 754 exceptions that get acted on”, by “interrupt the control flow” in paragraph 2.