# Is this fabs implementation valid for NaNs?

Tags: c, floating-point, language-lawyer

I have the following, relatively straightforward (though not very efficient), implementation of the `fabs` function:

```
double fabs(double x) {
  if (x == 0.0) return 0.0; // deals with both 0.0 and -0.0.
  if (x > 0.0) return x; // deals with ]0.0 .. +inf], but "(NaN > 0.0)" is false
  return -x; // deals with [-inf .. 0.0[, and NaNs
}
```

The only "gotcha" I found with this implementation is the fact that, given a positive NaN, it returns a negative one. However, I could not find in the standard anything saying that this is not allowed.

In particular, here's what I found:

§7.12.7 :

> Description
>
> The fabs functions compute the absolute value of a floating-point number x.
>
> Returns
>
> The fabs functions return |x|.

This does not impose any constraints of things that are not numbers, i.e. NaNs.

F.10.4.2 :

> The fabs functions
>
> — fabs(±0) returns +0.
>
> — fabs(±∞) returns +∞.
>
> The returned value is exact and is independent of the current rounding direction mode.

Again, no constraints on NaNs.

F.10, item 11:

> Functions with a NaN argument return a NaN result and raise no floating-point exception, except where stated otherwise.

No constraints on signedness.

In particular, I see no mention to the fact that `signbit(fabs(x))` should return 0 for any floating-point `x`, which is essentially what my implementation violates.

However, *Ignorantia juris non excusat*, therefore I'd like to be certain that this implementation is conforming. It does not help that the libc implementations I found (glibc, musl) use all sorts of low-level bit tricks or compiler built-ins to be efficient, and therefore do not provide much information in this case.

Just to clarify, I added the `language-lawyer` tag because I'm more interested in what the standard itself requires than in what the compilers themselves do, although if they do things in "unexpected" manners (e.g. MSVC seems to keep the minus sign for `-nan` as reported by @WeatherVane), this could confirm that the standard is not so strict (but then again, MSVC is not a good example of standards-conformance anyway...).

Comment: Given that `NaN` is "not a number", a negative "not a number" is pretty much the same a s positive. I don't think there is a meaning of a `NaN` sign. Given [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#NaN), `NaN` can have either sign.

Comment: The Wikipedia pages on floating point make no mention of ±NaN, only NaN, whereas they do distinguish ±0 and ±infinity. So if the value passed is `NaN` all you can return is `NaN`.

Comment: ...although MSVC does print `nan` or `-nan` depending on the sign bit.

Comment: ... and in the negative case, MSVC's `fabs` does not change its sign, it is still negative.

Comment: One (contrived) case where this might be problematic, would be e.g. if someone parses the output of my `fabs` function and considers that it would never start with a `-`, but the standard does not seem to give any guarantees concerning that: "[strtod] The expected form of the subject sequence is an optional plus or minus sign, then one of the following: (...) NAN or NAN(...)", so I tried finding a counterexample there, but I didn't so far.

Comment: It's asking for trouble (assuming the interest in NaNs). NaNs have many bits spare can can be used to pass about information, including sign. fabs() NaN should either do nothing or clear the sign bit, and the latter is preferable.

Comment: The value `NaN` does not arise from a computation, but from uninitialised data, or corruption (or in my case a contrived `union`) and since it isn't a number its sign is meaningless too, and so MSVC is wrong IMO to print its "sign", but correct not to change it in `fabs()`.

Comment: As far as C is concerned, NaN is an implementation detail. The relevant standard might be IEEE-754. In that case, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230129/sign-bit-of-a-nan-in-ieee-754-standard.

Comment: My previous remark was incorrect to say a NaN cannot arise from a compution: it can, for example `0 / 0` or `sqrt(-1)`.

Comment: Good question, yet it is curious that code attempts to invert the sign of +NaN and -NaN when it could have at least left NaNs alone with `... if (x < 0.0) return -x; return x;`

Comment: Code is valid in that it does not specifically invoke undefined behavior. It is not valid in that it does not insure the return has a positive sign when x is a NaN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C standard is lax about specifying floating-point behavior, except for annex F (which is optional), and a C implementation that conforms to the C standard without adopting annex F may behave as you indicate.

However, quality implementations will at least try to conform to IEEE 754-2008 (which is identical to the IEC 60559 mentioned in annex F of the C standard). IEEE 754-2008 says, in clause 5.5.1, that negating a floating-point operand (including a NaN) changes its sign bit.

Comment: Thanks! The following excerpt from 5.5.1 in particular seems to apply directly to my case: *abs(x) copies a floating-point operand x to a destination in the same format, setting the sign bit to 0 (positive).* Therefore, to sum up the answer to my question, it would be: *yes, it is valid w.r.t. to the C standard, but not according to the (optional) IEEE 754-2008 standard*.